Why isn't right click drag connecting to exit button on unwind segue
In the attached screen shot I have an app with a (A) Sign on view controller, (B) Feed VC, and (C) Settings VC.  I want the SettingsVC to have a log out button that unwinds back to the Sign on view controller.  On the sign on view controller's class I added unwind segue by typing
IBAction func unwindToSignUp(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
From everything I have read this should have enabled me to right click and drag from my sign out button to the exit button on the view controller to initiate the unwind segue, but when I right click drag like I have seen on multiple tutorials the blue line will not connect to the exit.  Is there something I can check to see that I have done wrong that would prevent this?  I restarted Xcode, I restarted my machine, and I am not sure what else to try.  My goal is to be able to navigate from A -> B -> C and then when button is tapped go from C -> A removing B from stack.
[
[

First, change your declaration from
@IBAction func unwindToSignUp(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

to
@IBAction func unwindToSignUp(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

Then, click on the Exit icon in the storyboard, and then click on the Connections tab. You will see your unwindToSignup: listed!

Drag from the empty circle to the button. When the word Action appears, click it.

